# Ajax request php file result without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a html file with a search form:

```
<form id="twit" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="venue" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Venue Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name ="location" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Venue City" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
        </span>
        </form>
```

With this search form a try to submit two query parameters to the twitter search api.

My php file is like this:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
//if(isset($_POST['venue']) && !empty($_POST['location'])){
    $venue = $_GET['venue'];
    $location = $_GET['location'];

    $getfield = "?q=$venue+$location&lang=en";
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
    //if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
        foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
        {
            //echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
            // Create map with request parameters
            $params = array ('txt' => $items['text']);

            // Build Http query using params
            $query = http_build_query ($params);

            // Create Http context details
            $contextData = array ( 
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                            'content'=> $query );

            // Create context resource for our request
            $context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

            // Read page rendered as result of your POST request
            $result =  file_get_contents (
                              'http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/',  // page url
                              false,
                              $context);

            // Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process 
            print_r($result."<br />");
        }   
//} //else {
    //echo "<h3 id='submit-error'>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Make sure you filled in all fields!</p><p><em>";
//}
//}
```

When I go to the url like this http://twitter.somewebsite.com/twitter.php?venue=test&location=washington I get the following from the sentiment engine (it takes a while any idea how I can speed it up? Api has this but dont know how I can incorporate that.A batch API has been added as the bottleneck for most of you will be in the network latency. To use it send a POST request with a JSON array of the texts you want to classify to http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/batch/. You will receive another JSON array of responses (similar to the one above) corresponding to the same order as in the request. The maximum content size can be 1 MB per request

With a onclick function I try this but nothing happens:

```
$.getJSON( "twitter.php", { venue: "ikea", location: "amsterdam" } )
    .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

I have little experience with PHp and almost no experience with ajax so thanks in advance.
So my questions are:

- How can i retrieve the twitter.php result back into my html file?
- Can I speed up the sentiment analysis with the batch if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following:

HTML:

```
<form id="twit">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="venue" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Venue Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name ="location" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Venue City" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
            </span>
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
$texts = array();
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
{
    $texts[] = $items['text'];
}   

$json_texts = json_encode($texts);

$ch = curl_init('http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/batch/');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_texts);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_texts))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "twitter.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg){
    } 
});
```